# Is it possible to add a class to another page with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm assuming the answer to this question is "no", but figured it was worth asking.

Is it possible to add a class to another page on click with jquery? For example:

Lets say I have two pages - "1.htm", and "2.htm". On 1.htm, I have two links like so:

```
<a href="2.htm" class="red">Go to page and make red</a>

<a href="2.htm" class="blue">Go to page and make blue</a>
```

If you click the first link, it would go to "2.htm", and add a class of "red" to the body of 2.htm.

If you click the second link, it would go to "2.htm", and add a class of "blue" to the body of 2.htm.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link to another page the browser loads the new page along with a whole new environment for Javascript - you can't continue execution on the new page since the original Javascript will have been discarded.

You can communicate with the new page though by passing a parameter somewhere. Javscript on the new page can retrieve the parameter and implement whatever it needs at that point.

Some options are:

- Add a parameter to the query string of the new page
- Write something to a cookie
- Store the required information in LocalStorage.

Which works best will depend on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you pass it in the query string and you parse it (either server side or client side) and add the class to that page.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your two pages are on the same domain (see Same Origin Policy: http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/same-origin-policy/) and as long as the 2.htm is opened within an iframe, this should not be a problem. 
Something like the below should work:

```
$(‘#iframe’).contents().find(‘.elementclass’).addClass(‘red’);
```